# How to disable submodules functionality for git repo with nested git repos?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have following repo structure:

```
/repo
  .git/
  subrepo1/
    .git/
    ...
  dir/
    subrepo2/
      .git/
      ...
  ...
  subrepoN/
    .git/
    ...
```

`subrepo`s are updated externally, but don't necessarily have a remote. `repo`'s purpose is to track all `subrepo`'s updates and introduce new changes in a single place. Updates will form a "vanilla" branch inside `repo`, which then will be periodically merged to "dev" branch. That's the intended workflow. Git by default refuses to track `subrepo`'s files, assuming they are non-configured submodules.

Questions is how do I disable such behaviour? I don't want to use submodules. I want Git to stop treating `subrepo`s as submodules, ignore every `subrepo`'s `.git` directory while keeping it, and to track all files from `subrepo`s. Preferably in `repo`'s `.git/config` file.

I looked through git manual, tried various things and couldn't acheive this. There is a valueable [workaround](http://debuggable.com/posts/git-fake-submodules:4b563ee4-f3cc-4061-967e-0e48cbdd56cb), but it still requires to execute `git add <subrepo-path>/` for each `subrepo`. Subtree approach isn't desireable, because it seemingly doubles space consumed and adds complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a simple way. Either you have to remove or rename `.git/` in subfolders or edit git sources (and recompile git) to disable recognition of `.git/` as submodules.

Comment: I already thought about renaming/deleting, but didn't thing about altering Git sources.